# CIFAR10 classification accuracy is not improved

Tags: python, pytorch, vgg-net

I am having trouble with loss_value not going down when I am learning using CIFAR10 with VGG16 that I built myself. What am I doing wrong?

```
class VGG16(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VGG16, self).__init__()
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
                        nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3,3),stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False),
                        nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False),
                        nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False),
                        nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False),
                        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU6(inplace=True),
                        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False),
                        )
        self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((7, 7))
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
                        nn.Linear(512*7*7,4096),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.Dropout(0.5,inplace=False),
                        nn.Linear(4096,4096),
                        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                        nn.Dropout(0.5,inplace=False),
                        nn.Linear(4096,10),
                       
        )
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = self.avgpool(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x
```

```
def train(model,train_loader,device):
# 交差エントロピー
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    # 確率的勾配降下法
    optimizer = optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=0.004)
    loss_values = []
    for epoch in range(100):
        running_loss = 0.0
        for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
            #print(i)
            inputs, labels = data
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(inputs.to(device))
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels.to(device))
            # 誤差逆伝播
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            train_loss = loss.item()
            running_loss += loss.item()
            if i % 500 == 499:
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' % (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 500))
                loss_values.append(running_loss/500)
                running_loss = 0.0
    plt.plot(loss_values)
    plt.show()
    #print('Finished Training')
    return model
def val(model,val_dataloader,device):
    model = model.eval()
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in val_dataloader:
            images, labels = data
            images = images.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            outputs = model(images)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            #print(outputs.data)
            #print((predicted == labels).sum())
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
    print('Accuracy of the network on images: %d %%' % (100 * correct / total))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model = (v.VGG16()).to(device)
    # ToTensor：画像のグレースケール化（RGBの0~255を0~1の範囲に正規化）、Normalize：Z値化（RGBの平均と標準偏差を0.5で決め打ちして正規化）
    transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

# トレーニングデータをダウンロード
    trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=100, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
# テストデータをダウンロード
    testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
    val_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
    #train_loader = torch.load("D:\Imagetrain.pt")
    #train_dataloader = data.DataLoader(train_loader, batch_size = 100, shuffle = True)
    #val_loader = torch.load("D:\Imagevalid.pt")
    #val_dataloader = data.DataLoader(val_loader, batch_size = 100, shuffle = True)
    print("VGG16")
    model = train(model,train_loader,device)
    
    val(model,val_dataloader,device)
```

[1,   500] loss: 5.94170756626129126232

[2,   500] loss: 2.30296494007110608138

[3,   500] loss: 2.30301657056808473101

[4,   500] loss: 2.30306150436401368964

[5,   500] loss: 2.30292595243453979137

[6,   500] loss: 2.30289011669158938389

[7,   500] loss: 2.30299579811096188919

[8,   500] loss: 2.30294379997253439996

[9,   500] loss: 2.30301538562774643637

[10,   500] loss: 2.30299294185638414589

[11,   500] loss: 2.30300025224685667169

[12,   500] loss: 2.30288641500473012513

[13,   500] loss: 2.30299068164825460059

[14,   500] loss: 2.30296789026260384503

[15,   500] loss: 2.30289178085327161938

[16,   500] loss: 2.30295993375778218493

[17,   500] loss: 2.30295620632171615938

[18,   500] loss: 2.30287832784652701790

[19,   500] loss: 2.30305475187301622597

[20,   500] loss: 2.30294395494461046070

[21,   500] loss: 2.30296932125091569077

[22,   500] loss: 2.30293812608718884150

[23,   500] loss: 2.30294448757171643649

[24,   500] loss: 2.30292115163803101652

[25,   500] loss: 2.30291592741012562939

[26,   500] loss: 2.30301268148422222382

[27,   500] loss: 2.30291447067260746095

[28,   500] loss: 2.30297159337997436879

Comment: Have you tried overfitting your data with a reduced sample of your original dataset?

Comment: How should I do it?

Comment: Reduce your dataset size

Comment: I over-fitted the data but it does not change.

Comment: No overfitting means making your model learn on that data without the ability to generalize outside that training data. Did you manage to do that? If not it means you have an issue in your model. Are you certain this is the exact VGG implementation?

Comment: Have you considered using BN layers to your network? The original VGG paper did not have them but they had to train the network in a layer-wise method for that reason. Without BN, you'll have issues training a NN this deep from scratch